# Easy deployment of a jvm based web server on a remote machine

Tags: java, kotlin, server, development-environment, remote-server

I wanted to know what is the easiest way to deploy a web server made using java or kotlin. With `nodejs`, I just keep all the server code on remote machine and edit it using the `sshfs` plugin for vscode. For jvm based servers, this doesn't appear as easy since intellij doesn't provide remote editing support. Is there a method for jvm based servers which allows quick iterative development cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to keep your server code on remote machine? How about developing and testing it locally, and only when you want to test it on the actual deployment site, then deploy it?

I once tried to use SSH-FS with IntelliJ, and because of the way IntelliJ builds its cache, the performance was terrible. The caching was in progress, but after 15 minutes I gave up. And IntelliJ without its caching and smart hints would be close to a regular editor.

In my professional environment, I also use Unison from time to time: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/. I have it configured in a way to copy only code, not the generated sources. Most of the times it works pretty well, but it tends to have its quirks which can make you waste half a day on debugging it.

To sum up, I see such options:

1. Developing and testing locally, and avoiding frequent deployments to the remote machine.
2. VSCode with `sshfs` plugin, because why not, if it's enough for you for `nodejs`?
3. A synchronization tool like Unison.

Related answers regarding SSHFS from IntelliJ Support (several years old, but, I believe, still hold true):

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206592225-Indexing-on-a-project-hosted-via-SSHFS-makes-pycharm-unusable-disable-indexing-
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206599275-Working-directly-on-remote-project-via-ssh-

Answer (score 0):

A professional deployment won't keep source code on the remote server, for several reasons:

1. **It's less secure.** If you can change your running application by editing source code and recompiling (or even if edits are deployed automatically), it's that much easier for an attacker to do the same.
2. **It's less stable.** What happens to users who try to access your application while you are editing source files or recompiling? At best, they get an error page; at worst, they could get a garbage response, or even a leak of customer data.
3. **It's less testable.** If you edit your source code and deploy immediately, how do you test to ensure that your application works? Throwing untested buggy code directly at your users is highly unprofessional.
4. **It's less scalable.** If you can keep your source code on the server, then by definition you only have one server.  (Or, slightly better, a small number of servers that share a common filesystem.) But that's not very scalable: you're clearly hosted in only one geographic location and thus vulnerable to all kinds of single points of failure. A professional web-scale deployment will need to be geographically distributed and redundant at every level of the application.

If you want a "quick iterative development cycle" then the best way to do that is with a **local development environment**, which may involve a *local VM* (managed with something like Vagrant) or a *local container* (managed with something like Docker). VMs and containers both provide mechanisms to map a local directory containing your source code into the running application server.